# This requires the 'super-parameters' language feature to be enabled

Tags: flutter

I am using super keyword in initState method.but i am getting this error 'This requires the 'super-parameters' language feature to be enabled.
Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.16.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'.dart(experiment_not_enabled)'.Need help please.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm getting this message whenever I try to use `super.param` the same way I use `this.param` in a constructor. It's a relatively new feature in Dart.

Answer (score 20):

`super-parameters` were added in Dart `2.17.0`.

If you're not already using the latest version, run

```
flutter upgrade
```

To use `super-parameters` in your app, open your `pubspec.yaml` file and update `sdk` to target min `2.17.0`:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: Don't forget to run `flutter pub get` in the end.

Comment: I'm having same issue. Running Dart 2.18.6, did ```flutter upgrade``` and ```flutter pub get``` afterwards. same thing. Any idea what else could be wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Also, if you have

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"
```

and you still have an error, try to upgrade you dependencies:

```
flutter packages upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

change 2.16 to 2.17 in  pubspec.yaml file  that solved my problem don't do upgrade after that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

environment:
sdk: '>=3.1.0 <4.0.0'

The above are current Version to work on.